# When is a child class too different to be inherited?

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, vector, polymorphism

I have a set of closely linked data structures that feel like they ought to be inherited. However, they are different in that children have some extra variables. I can achieve this via:

```
struct A {
int a;
int b;
virtual int kind()=0;
A(int a_, int b_) : a{a_}, b{b_} {};
}

struct B: A {
int c;
int kind() {return 1;};
B(int a_, int b_, int c_) : A(a_, b_), c{c_} {};
}

struct C : A {
int d;
int kind() {return 2;};
C(int a_, int b_, int d_) : A(a_, b_), d{d_} {};
}
```

But if I want to iterate through a vector of these and access variables of a derived class it starts to become a bit messy:

```
std::vector<A*> v;
v.push_back(new B(1,1,1));
v.push_back(new C(1,1,2));

for (A* bar : v) {
    if (bar->kind() == 1) {
        auto *bar_ = dynamic_cast<B*>(A);
        std::cout << bar_->c << std::endl;
    } else if (bar->kind() == 2) {
        auto *bar_ = dynamic_cast<C*>(A);
        std::cout << bar_->d << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Is this sort of thing normal, or am I missing something and breaking some important rule? Most examples I find for inheritance don't have different important member variables or methods, just the same ones implemented differently.

Comment: As a good rule of thumb, any use of `dynamic_cast` is a red flag: something is wrong in your design.

Comment: I would say that this is a bad design choice. If you have pointers to the base class and want to acces the object through that you should have a uniform interface. So all object can be dealt with without having to care what type they are. Otherwise maybe you should store them in a different manner to begin with.

Comment: On an unrelated note, you should use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>>` so you don't have to deal with manual memory management.

Comment: `dynamic_cast<B *>(A);` is strange, you should cast a variable, not a type, you may have meant `auto *bar_ = dynamic_cast<B *>(bar);`

Comment: As a rule of thumb, using `dynamic_cast` to downcast (e.g. convert a `Base *` to a `Derived *`) is a pretty significant hint that the derived class should not be derived from the base class. In your case, a simpler design would be for the base class to provide a `virtual` function called (say) `toString()` to print all the data of an object to a string and (if necessary) `toDerivedString()` which does the same, but only for the most derived class members (and prints nothing by default). Your loop could then call those functions direct - without testing the actual type of the object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've already done the work of creating the virtual base class. Instead of returning the kind as a value you can just overload the functions where you want to do separate things.

```
struct A {
  virtual ~A() = default;
  int a;
  int b;
  virtual int get_value() const = 0;
  A(int a_, int b_) : a{a_}, b{b_} {};
}

struct B: A {
  int c;
  int get_value() const override {return c;};
  B(int a_, int b_, int c_) : A(a_, b_), c{c_} {};
}

struct C : A {
  int d;
  int get_value() const override {return d;};
  C(int a_, int b_, int d_) : A(a_, b_), d{d_} {};
}
```

Note that I have used the `override` specifier here. This is a good practice in modern c++ for readability and also for code safety.

Now, we can use the virtual function to simplify the main code

```
std::vector<A*> v;
v.push_back(new B(1,1,1));
v.push_back(new C(1,1,2));
        
for (auto* bar : v) {
  std::cout << bar->get_value() << std::endl;
}

// ... do something else with v

// clean up the memory

for (auto *bar : v) {
  delete bar;
}
```

Remember to define a virtual destructor in the base class. This ensures that when we delete the `A*` in the vector `v` the destructor of the inherited class is also called and we don't get a memory leak.

Comment: Instead of manual delete loop, use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>> v;` and deletion will happen automatically. (you'll have to make it `auto& bar : v` in the main loop, too).

Comment: Yes I would always recommend a smart pointer in modern code, however I didn't want to change the base container structure away from the original question as using a raw pointer might be the only option for the OP.